# Kubectl with Bash command is always passed in LowerCase and not CamelCase

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

Consider the Bash code:

```
function dropMyDB() {
  kubectl -n $1 exec -ti $1-CLUSSTER-0 -- psql -d MYDBNAME -U postgres -c "truncate table "$2";"
}

dropMyDB $1 "myTableNameInCamelCase"
```

When I execute the code it produces:

```
ERROR:  relation "mytablenameincamelcase" does not exist
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Which means that the table name is not passed in its CamelCase form.

How can we fix this ?

Comment: Try using singlequotes to get the camelcase

Comment: @VigneshRamsubbose: In single quotes the bash get the `$2` as a literal string "$2".

Comment: does your bash code work with missing 'then' in if loop?

Comment: @VigneshRamsubbose: I've written this code from memory in Notepad , fixed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First

Escape your `"$2"` because it is inside another double quote

```bash
postgres -c "truncate table "$2";"

# to
postgres -c "truncate table $2;"

# or
postgres -c "truncate table \"$2\";"
```

#### Second

You can test that the issue is not [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```bash
function dropMyDB() {
  echo "kubectl -n $1 exec -ti $1-CLUSSTER-0 -- psql -d MYDBNAME -U postgres -c \"truncate table \"$2\";\""
}

dropMyDB $1 "myTableNameInCamelCase"
```

Then

```bash
chmod +x script.sh

./script.sh foo
kubectl -n foo exec -ti foo-CLUSSTER-0 -- psql -d MYDBNAME -U postgres -c "truncate table "myTableNameInCamelCase";"
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's no kubectl's fault:

```
fun(){ k exec aaaaaaaaaaaaa -it -- echo "$1"; }
fun AdsdDasfsFsdsd
AdsdDasfsFsdsd
```

But probably psql's one, try it like this:

```
... psql -d MYDBNAME -U postgres -c "truncate table '$2';"
```

Comment: Doesn't work ,but thanks.